# Import Tab Delimited File into MATLAB with characters AND numbers

Tags: matlab, csv

I am attempting to import a file that is created with a Fortran program that includes four columns: Atomic Symbol, X Position, Y Position, Z Position. Here's an example of input file:

```
Zn               0.00000000000       0.00000000000       0.00000000000
Zn               0.00000000000       0.00000000000       0.25000000000
Zn               0.00000000000       0.00000000000       0.50000000000
Zn               0.00000000000       0.00000000000       0.75000000000
Zn               0.00000000000       0.05000000000       0.00000000000
Zn               0.00000000000       0.05000000000       0.25000000000
Zn               0.00000000000       0.05000000000       0.50000000000
Zn               0.00000000000       0.05000000000       0.75000000000
```

Now, if I import this in excel and export as a CSV file and then use csvread(filename), an error is produced, presumable because the first column has character inputs. (I'm sure there is a way to import tab delimited files directly without this intermediary step, but I've been using this method.)

Things I've tried:

1. Removing the first column before importing into MATLAB. The problem with this is I will be dealing with compounds that have multiple atom types, and I want to be able to keep track of them.
2. I know I can use double(variable) and char(variable) to translate from characters to a numeric array, but I still need to be able to import the file before I change the first column to a numeric array.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe use [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html?searchHighlight=importdata)? You can split text data and numbers easily to process them individually

Comment: I haven't been able to get importdata to work for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
fid = fopen('test.dat');
%one string and 3 numbers
format= '%s %f %f %f';
C = textscan(fid);
fclose(fid);
% C is now [{8x1cell} {8x1double} {8x1double} {8x1double}]
%get the content from C(1) and make a cell array out of C(2:4)  
C= [C{:,1} num2cell([C{2:4}])];
```

Comment: Go a little further. That reads in everything in a cell array. How would you convert the last three columns into a numeric matrix for use?

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction, but this create a 1x3 cell 'C' where each cell is in turn a 3200x1 cell (so, I have a nested cell in each C spot). How I can I have C be a 3200x4 cell, and have each row be a row from the input file?

Comment: i see. well the 3200x4 part is easy i will edit my answer, but how do you want to proceed from there? is there a chance you have a file with a different format? do you want them to be sorted by elements or plot a 3D image of it? are you aware of the different types in matlab (cell, struct, matrix)? please edit the question so we can find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

%% You could import the data directly by using readtable (it accepts .txt, .dat, or .csv and spreadsheet formats).

% Import data as a table using readtable

```
   data = readtable('filename.txt', 'Delimiter', 'tab');
```

%% See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html for more on the function.

%% See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html for detailed information on table.